# Remove div and style it to a{}

Tags: html, css

I am using this HTML:

```
 <nav class="submenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text">DISKUSNÍ FÓRUM </span><div class="arrows"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text">KOMENTÁŘE  </span><div class="arrows"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text">ZÁZNAM CHATU </span><div class="arrows"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text">UŽÍVATELÉ </span><div class="arrows"></div></a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

To make something like: 
[image]

It works cool, the thing is I feel like the `<div class="arrows">` is pointless there and I can style it in `.submenu ul li a{` or something but whatever I try it doesn't work how I want, so is here anybody who can help me to remove `<div class="arrows">` without changing how it looks on site?

CSS:

```
.submenu{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width:780px;
}

.submenu a{
    width: 187px;
    display: block;
}

.submenu ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;         
}

.submenu ul li {
background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #1A6EB6;
display: inline-block;
height: 38px;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative; /* added this */
width: 187px;
}

.submenu ul li:hover {
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg_hover.png");             
}

.submenu ul li .text {
    color: #1A6EB6;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 182px; 
}


.submenu ul li .arrows {
    background-image: url("images/arrows.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 10px; 
    top: 6px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 17px;
}

.submenu ul li:hover .arrows{
    background-position: -3px -14px;         
}
```

Comment: You want to remove arrows?

Comment: nope want to remove <div> </div> but still have arrows displayed

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/w6gVG/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, but this remove backgroun of <li> when its not :hover and unfortunately not display arrows, if u want to try it live, here is arrows http://funedit.com/andurit/new/images/arrows.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element to display your arrow :

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/D2STC/3/)**

```
.submenu ul li:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url("images/arrows.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 10px; 
    top: 6px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 17px;
}

.submenu ul li:hover:after{
    background-position: -3px -14px;         
}
```

And you can remove the `div.arrows`

Comment: hey man, thanks for your answer, the thing is i am displaying background of the li already in .submenu ul li {}

Comment: i am really thankfull for your help, but this is not working as well :(, this is fiddle of your code with corret image links http://fiddle.jshell.net/D2STC/1/

Comment: @user258459 sorry I forgot the `content:""` on the `:after` here it is working : http://fiddle.jshell.net/D2STC/3/

Comment: @web-tiki I also use `:after` in my fiddle but if he make more space between arrows on image he can just style the anchor with background right no-repeat ;)